# Cassandra Quorum : Consistency Level

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a 3 DC ring in Cassandra with each DC having a 4 node cluster. So its 4 nodes*3(DC) = 12 nodes. I'm testing how Cassandra behaves when some nodes go down when we have `Quorum` consistency level. We have set a replication factor of 3 on each datacenter. So our

`Quorum = Floor(Sum of Replication FActor/2) + 1. RF = 3 quorum= 5.`

In theory if I have five nodes in my 12 node cluster, I should be good for read and write. So I brought down a full Datacenter DC1, and 3 nodes in another datacenter(Dc2). So I have 1 node up in DC2 and whole of DC3(4 nodes). I have 5 nodes up. By theory, this should be good for my writes to be succesfull in quorum consistency. But, when I ran, I get

`Cassandra.Unavailable Exception: Not enough replica available for query at consistency ONE (5 required but only 4 alive)`.

But, I do have 5 nodes alive. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

Quorum is for the entire cluster and Local_Quorum is for a single Data center. Just some basics to understand, cassandra is distributed systems meaning data is distributed in your cluster with each node owning a primary range and at the same time replicating data of other nodes. This means nodes which are responsible to store a piece of data are the only nodes which are calculated for Consistency.  In your case 5 nodes are up does not mean Quorum consistency is met for the writes or reads, because the DC with all nodes up will definitely have data in atleast 3 nodes (remember your RF is 3), but the DC with only 1 node will either have or not have data you are querying.

In your case if you hit the DC with all node up using a Local_quorum you will get correct results.

Answer (score 1):

QUORUM by itself, refers to members of same data-center.
Which in your case DC3 has of 4.
But you asked for QUORUM of 5, which DC3 cannot provide.
That is why there is concept like ONE and LOCAL_ONE.

I am pretty sure you will get same error at QUORUM 5, even if your all DC nodes are up.

You can refer : http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

Comment: "QUORUM by itself, refers to members of same data-center."  Not correct.  What you are describing is LOCAL_QUORUM.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I'm not sure if quorum means a local group within a dc. From what I have read, it is a number describing a majority. So, if you have 6 nodes and replication factor of 4. We get quorum = rf/2 + 1 => 3. if we set, our write consistency is quorum, then write is successfull only after it gets confirmation from 3 nodes.

Comment: Hi Aaron, My queston is, is the number 3 along with the co-ordinator node or just any 3 nodes ? And how this number varies if it is a multi-dc architecture. Any links would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Aaron, you can set the consistency level to whatever you want, when you create the session to make connection to your cassandra cluster in code. So, not sure why you keep on calculating default quorum.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the operations should and will fail.

From the DC that is up you can guarantee at any time 3 replicas, RF 3.

The node up in the other DC has ~60% to nail down another replica.

3 + 1 = 4.

You`re asking for CL 5.

5 > 4 => fail.